# How to get GHC to apply my orphaned instances `HasServer` and `HasClient` for `AuthProtect`?

Tags: haskell, instance, servant, orphan

I use the `AuthProtect` combinator from [servant: Servant.API.Experimental.Auth](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.18/docs/Servant-API-Experimental-Auth.html). There is not much code there, the instance `HasServer (AuthProtect tag)` is in `servant-server` and the insance `HasClient (AuthProtect tag)` in whatever servant client you use.

I use `servant-snap` instead of `servant-server` and a custom `HasClient` implementation for an `obelisk` project, with a project structure that consists of three cabal packages:

- frontend (compiled by ghcjs)
- common (compiled by ghcjs *and* ghc)
- backend (compiled by ghc)

I used to have a custom implementation of `AuthProtect` along with the instances in the `common` package. However, `common` can neither depend on `servant-snap` nor on `snap-core` because of ghcjs.

Now I moved the `HasServer` instance to the backend ... no problem, right? Wrong. Once the `HasServer` instance is orphaned, ghc does not correctly resolve my api type anymore. It's just as if the orphaned instance were not there at all.

Why is that?

What is there, I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of those solves my problem:

```
instance HasServer api context m => HasServer (AuthProtect "jwt" :> api) context m where
  type ServerT (AuthProtect "jwt" :> api) context m =
    String -> ServerT api context m

  hoistServerWithContext _ pc nt s = hoistServerWithContext (Proxy :: Proxy api) pc nt . s

  route (Proxy :: Proxy (AuthProtect "jwt" :> api)) context subserver =
    route (Proxy :: Proxy api) context (subserver `addAuthCheck` withRequest authCheck)
      where
        authCheck :: Request -> DelayedM m String
        authCheck =
          liftIO . evalSnap (pure "account info")
                            (\x -> pure $! (x `seq` ()))
                            (\f -> let !_ = f 0 in pure ())
```

If I don't want specialize to `AuthProtect "jwt"` for some reason, I have to provide the constraint `KnownSymbol tag`.

```
instance (KnownSymbol tag, HasServer api context m) => HasServer (AuthProtect tag :> api) context m where
  type ServerT (AuthProtect tag :> api) context m =
    String -> ServerT api context m

  hoistServerWithContext _ pc nt s = hoistServerWithContext (Proxy :: Proxy api) pc nt . s

  route (Proxy :: Proxy (AuthProtect tag :> api)) context subserver =
    route (Proxy :: Proxy api) context (subserver `addAuthCheck` withRequest authCheck)
      where
        authCheck :: Request -> DelayedM m String
        authCheck =
          liftIO . evalSnap (pure "account info")
                            (\x -> pure $! (x `seq` ()))
                            (\f -> let !_ = f 0 in pure ())
```

Answer (score 1):

Instances are global... in theory. In practice, to support separate compilation, they propagate via imports. So import the module that defines the instance from the module that uses it. Importing it transitively is good enough -- i.e. importing a module that imports a module that imports the module that defines the instance.

Comment: That is my assumption, too. I import the module where I define the orphaned instance, already. Maybe I'll try and put together a minimal example that shows this behavior.

Comment: @ruben.moor A minimal reproducing example is always welcome in such questions.

Comment: those minimal example can do wonders. I fixed my problem by replacing `AuthProtect tag` with `AuthProtect "jwt"`. If I want to keep it general, I have to add "KnownSymbol tag" to the instance constraints.